# Can a button have a two segues to two different view controllers / how can i code a view controller change without a segue?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

This is what i have now, but it doesn't open the view controller. I dont think my let act1c = act1ViewController() works.

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let act1vc = act1ViewController()

    let act2vc = activity2VC()

    switch sender.titleLabel?.text {
    case "cheer up":
     present(act1vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case "yay":
        present(act2vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    default:
        break
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 segues from one button, but then you'd have to conditionally cancel one in an override of `func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool` and that would be a confusing design.

I'd recommend wiring your two segues from the viewController icon at the top of the ViewController.  Give them identifiers such as `"segueToAct1"` and `"segueToAct2"` in the *Attributes Inspector* and then trigger them with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    switch sender.titleLabel?.text {
    case "cheer up":
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToAct1", sender: nil)

    case "yay":
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToAct2", sender: nil)

    default:
        break
    }
}
```